# How to make multiple request with Ajax on a single page?

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongodb

I'm trying to make a Quiz Web Application. Basically I want to make a single page application in database there will be a Array question each question have 4 option user have to choose one option and click on next button after clicking on next button there will be another question but on the same page. So like this there will be a 100 questions each time user have to select one option and click on next button and then user will get another question on the same page.,How i can do this with ajax ?